# App bundle (.abb) size is bigger than APK (.apk), should not be the opposite?

Tags: android

The code is practically the same, I just added one class, is it because when the Bundle is installed in a device just a part of it is going to go to that device and its size is going to be lower?

[image]

Comment: Not much idea regarding exact issue but do you have any native libraries or third party jars?

Comment: download size will be smaller, it is not the abb size.

Comment: Hi, this is Pierre from Google. This looks suspicious indeed, the bundle shouldn't be that much bigger than your previous APK if you haven't changed anything to your dependencies or proguard configuration. If you're able to share the package name, I can give a closer look. Alternatively, you can contact Play Console support team and they can take this information from you privately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/)

> Google Play’s Dynamic Delivery uses your Android App Bundle to build
>   and serve APKs that are optimized for each device configuration. This
>   results in a smaller app download for end-users by removing unused
>   code and resources needed for other devices.

So basically apk will be build using Dynamic delivery which will combine only necessary resources and will ensure that the build installed on particular design is optimized. There is no mention that bundle size is smaller, but it ensures that download size for end user will be less.

Also [this](https://medium.com/googleplaydev/what-a-new-publishing-format-means-for-the-future-of-android-2e34981793a) a good article to refer to.

Mentionig some key points mentioned in it

> - Step 1: You write all your code for your app in an IDE such as    Android Studio or a games engine such as Unity as you normally would.
> - Step 2: Now, when you’re ready to test or release the app, you build    it as an Android App Bundle, Android’s new app publishing
>     format. You    still sign the app so that Google Play can verify it’s
>     from you.
> - Step 3: If you haven’t already, you opt in to app signing by Google Play.    If you’re releasing a new app, you can do this in a one-click
>     process    when you upload your app. When you opt in, Play designates
>     the first    key you used to sign your app bundle as the upload key.
>     This is just    for security identification purposes and, if you ever
>     lose it, you    can contact Google to verify your identity and reset
>     it. For existing    apps, you need to visit the app signing page in
>     the Play Console and    securely transfer your app signing key to
>     Google Play. Why do you    need to do this? Continue to step 4 to find
>     out.
> - Step 4: When you    upload your app bundle to Google Play, Play processes it and    generates split APKs signed with the app signing
>     key for every    possible device configuration and language that you
>     support. Split    APKs are an Android platform feature introduced in
>     Android L. As long    as each split APK is signed with the same key,
>     the Android platform    will treat them as one app. You can think of a
>     split APK as ‘part’ of    an APK: to run the app, the device treats
>     all the parts as a single    app.
> - Step 5: When a user installs the app, Play delivers the base    split APK (all the code that’s common for every device), the language 
>     split APKs (for the languages the user speaks), and the device
>     configuration split APKs (for the device’s screen size and the CPU
>     architecture). This means the device gets just what it needs without
>     wasted space. For updates to be accepted by the device, every
>     release’s split APKs must be signed with the same app signing key as
>     the original app install.

Comment: Thanks a lot Karan!

Comment: The App Bundle should be of similar size than the APK though. The fact that it's almost twice the size shows that something else has been put in there.

Comment: The size can be bigger if you have native libraries for different ABI's