# Why AAB size is much bigger than APK build size in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, apk, size, android-app-bundle

I've built a game using Unity. Integrated Admob and Unity ads. But when I build .apk its size is around 85mb but when I build .aab its size increases to 101mb.
I'm currently using Unity 2018.4.7.
Kindly help.

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095304/app-bundle-abb-size-is-bigger-than-apk-apk-should-not-be-the-opposite).

Comment: There are many reasons. One of the big ones is that the app bundle is not a file that gets deployed on phones so it doesn't have to be optimized. You can use bundletool to measure the size of the APKs as they will be downloaded from Play Store to compare apples to apples.